# Give a regular expression for the set of strings over {a, b, c} such that the number of a's equals the number of b's and is equal to 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

How would I describe from finite automata to regular expressions?

I know how I would describe it if there were to be just one or more number of a's and b's using + but I'm not sure how to go about it to make it exactly 2.

So far my thought process has been:

These are the possibilities of the strings with 2 a's and 2 b's: aabb, abab, bbaa, abab, abba, baab. Now I need to add in the c's, but it doesn't matter where it is placed - so it would be c*?

Comment: Take all the regexps that have 2 a's and 2 b's and precedde, postfix and intersperse with $c^*$.

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with. How can I express the strings that only have 2 a's and 2 b's?

Comment: No way around it: write down aabb, abab, etc. . If someone has a nearly magical way to do this I would be glad to see that.

Comment: But if the placement of c doesn't matter, how would I indicate that? For example, if I do (aabb)c* wouldnt that mean the c has to come after aabb? It feels a little inefficient to write it out for every single one

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't see that you have already exercised and written down all those possibilities with a and b. Just change xyzu to c*xc*yc*zc*uc*.

Comment: O, the system lost some stars after the c's.

Answer (score 1):

To summarise what others have already put in the comments: this regular expression will do the job:

`c*ac*ac*bc*bc*|c*ac*bc*ac*bc*|c*bc*ac*ac*bc*|c*ac*bc*bc*ac*|c*bc*ac*bc*ac*|c*bc*bc*ac*ac*`

Comment: Please use mathjax, and take more care with your formatting.  What does "|" mean?

Comment: @amWhy This was meant to be a regular expression in the syntax of "extended regular expressions" (thereby not really suited to MathJax) with "|" meaning "alternation" (i.e. `r|s` is matched when `r` *or* `s` are matched). This may not be the syntax the OP was looking for, but is one I've  most frequently encountered in various applications (including Perl and ECMAScript/JavaScript).

Comment: @amWhy "|" in the context of regular expression corresponds exactly to a union of the respective sets.